# Passing a query to controller and display on view in mvc?

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I have this query which I can't seem to handle. 
The idea is to create a list of the "best selling prints" in my store.

The query is Ok now, but I'm not very comfortable with mvc yet so I'm not sure how I should pass this through the controller and how to print it out in the view. I've watched a lot of tutorials, still I find myself trying and failing... I hope someone can help me with this. (I'll cut through some parts of the code which I think that won't help but if I'm missing something out please say so).

**model.php**

```
 <?php

 class model {


    function getBestSelling() {

    $sql = "SELECT fk_print_id as printId, COUNT(print_for_sale_id) as saleCount
            FROM print_for_sale
            GROUP BY fk_print_id
            ORDER BY saleCount DESC";
    $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    return $this->buildArr($result);
} 
}
```

**controller.php**

```
 class Controller {

    function bestselling() {
    $arr = $this->model->getBestSelling($result);
    echo $result;
    include 'views/home.php'; 

    }
```

**home.php (view)**

```
  <div>

<h2>Top 3 Bestsellers</h2>
    <ul>
       <li>1st</li>
       <li>2nd</li>
       <li>3rd</li>
    </ul>

 </div>
```

What am I doing wrong in the model and controller and how can I pass this to the view?
Thank you!

Comment: whats output of  echo $result; ?

Comment: It does nothing...doesn't show up. :/

Comment: What result you get..?? any error..??? can please specify your exact problem..

Comment: which framework are you using ?

Comment: I don't get any error because I can't seem to pass it to the view. I'm confused and not sure how to do it. The echo is doing nothing.

Comment: I'm not using a framework. I did it from scratch. But it's mvc. I have a model.php , controller.php,  index.php and views!

Comment: try print_r() in the place of  echo $result; and whats the result or any error ?

Comment: No, no errors. Nothing shows up. I believe it's because I have nothing in my home.php (view), no? I'm not sure what to put there in order to print my result..

Comment: When I put the print_r($result) in the home.php it gets me this: "Notice: Undefined variable: result in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/printstore2/views/home.php on line 13" @A.P.

Comment: You can't use $this->model in your controller unless you define it in the controller. Likely should be `$yada = new model(); $yada->getBestSelling($result);`

Comment: I have this in the controller :

 `function __construct() {
        $this->model = new model();
    }`
@Rasclatt

Comment: @Owly have you checked my solution... can you please try that...